# How to check keyspace and table size in Amazon Keyspaces

Tags: database, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

We recently migrated from Cassandra to AWS Keyspaces and I am just wondering how to check for table and keyspace total size in AWS keyspaces.
Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

currently there is no direct way to get the keyspace/table storage metrics, but you can certainly calculate the storage size if you are aware of no.of rows in the table

size of each row is calculate based on

```
partition key columns + clustering columns + regular columns + row metadata = total encoded size of row
```

for more info on how to calculate refer

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/working-with-rows.html#calculating-row-size

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/cql.elements.html#cql.data-types

FYI you will be able to see the storage in the cost explorer

Answer (score 1):

[Now](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/06/amazon-keyspaces-monitor-table-storage-costs-amazon-cloudwatch/), you can use the [BillableTableSizeInBytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/metrics-dimensions.html) CloudWatch metric to monitor and track your table storage costs over time. The BillableTableSizeInBytes metric provides the billable storage size of a table by summing up the encoded size of all the rows in the table.

Additionally, its easy to aggregate this into a keyspace using cloudwatch metric math.

```
SUM(SEARCH('{AWS/Cassandra,Keyspace,TableName} Keyspace="tlp_stress" MetricName="BillableTableSizeInBytes"', 'Average', 300))
```

You can find pre-built dashboard for a keyspace and table in the following git repository. By using the cloudformation template provided you can create a new dashboard quickly.
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-cloudwatch-cloudformation-templates

The following image is cloud watch of storage size.
[image: Storage size for keyspace]

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have multiply number of rows * row_size
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/working-with-rows.html#calculating-row-size